# Google Domains Squarespace problem

Tags: google-domains

I am a Google Domain website owner. In 2023, Google Domains is being migrated to Squarespace. During this time, They sent me a link to Squarespace, and for months I have logged into Squarespace successfully, and I am able to view my domains. Today, I am no longer able to log into Squarespace account. I have attempted an account recovery using my phone number and email addresses, but no message is ever received on my phone or email inboxes.
I have tried
Restart PC
2 browsers
Disable all adblockers and other extensions
Using Incognito Mode
Clear Cookies and Cache
Allow Browser Notifications
Used both SquareSpace Web & mobile App versions

SquareSpace only provides email support, and they have not helped me get back into my account, after several conversations.

Why did it work for months, and how do I get into my account now? Thank you.